# Problem in send flutter actions to receive in swift

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I'm trying send some action in flutter, clicked by a button or another things, and receive in swift to get this action and do other action inside swift

I'm using Swift 5 in the background application, and using flutter..

I'm expected create a integration in flutter and swift with Spotify SDK, but, i need when click in button, active all connections with spotify in swift and after send to flutter the response, not automatically, and in spotify tutorial don't explain this, and i dont find in anywhere someone using this type application, please i really need help

Comment: Can you add a code example maybe we can help?

Comment: this is the fact, i don't know how can i start this code, what i have is in when i generate automatically in flutter plugin